# Combination for safe in Dishonored The Royal Physician mission

Tags: dishonored

Where can I find the combination for the safe behind the painting on the wall of the ruined building in The Royal Physician mission?

Answer (score 2):

The combination is 294 and it is given to you if you disable the wall of light for the prisoners.

Comment: I did that by removing the whale oil but don't recall seeing 294 anywhere.  Does it matter if the prisoners get killed by guards?

Comment: You must get rid of the guards first, and then when you release the prisoners the woman will thank you and tell you the combination for the safe behind the painting.

Comment: @Pyritie There is no need for spoiler tags here, since there is just no way to accidentally find this answer and still be surprised about spoilers. Also, spoiler tags are useful only if the answer can stand on its own without the spoiled text.

Answer (score 1):

Disable the wall of light for the prisoners. You can do this quite easily by **disconnecting the whale oil tank**. Afterwards, a person will thank you and give you the code 294.